# How to display something on the STM32L476 LCD Display

Tags: c, stm32

I am working on board STM32L476 and I want to display any word(e.g `Hello world` ) on its built-in LCD. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The [STM32CubeL4](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubel4.html) package from  ST (free registration required to download) has plenty of examples and documentation aimed at beginners. Just ask another question with the specific problem when you happen to have one later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already downloaded  STM32CubeL4 (STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.13.0) and I was build the project (32L476GDISCOVERY) on keil all of them example show error, some example show 47 error and some 22 error, so what I do ?